# How to use @formula when not inquiring the same table

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to get data from a profile table from a @Vote entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vote")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Vote implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
private Instant creationDate;

@Column(name = "number_of_points")
private Integer numberOfPoints;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@NotNull
@JsonIgnoreProperties("")
private User user;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@NotNull
@JsonIgnoreProperties("votes")
private Proposal proposal;

@Formula("(SELECT SUM(number_of_points) FROM VOTE WHERE VOTE.USER_ID = USER_ID)")
int totalVotes;

@Formula("(SELECT USER_POINTS FROM PROFILE WHERE PROFILE.USER_ID = 1)")
Long userVotes;
```

It works within the same table, as if I ask for Vote data like in this case....

```
@Formula("(SELECT SUM(number_of_points) FROM VOTE WHERE VOTE.USER_ID = USER_ID)")
int totalVotes;
```

but not when I ask

```
@Formula("(SELECT USER_POINTS FROM PROFILE WHERE PROFILE.USER_ID = 1)")
Long userVotes;
```

and I can not find any documentation that says there is a limitation. Thanks

PD: By the way, the SQL statement works in the database.

```
entity User{
}

entity Profile {
    creationDate Instant required
    image ImageBlob
    userPoints Long min(100)
}

entity Vote {
    creationDate Instant required
    numberOfPoints Integer
}

// RELATIONSHIPS:
relationship OneToOne {
    Profile{user(id) required} to User{profile}
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Vote{user(id) required} to User
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach, hope it will work for you.

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT r.id FROM Result r WHERE resultDate = (SELECT MAX(sqr.resultDate) FROM Result sqr WHERE sqr.test_id = id))", referencedColumnName="id")),
    })
private Long userVotes;
```

Comment: Thanks, Irfan. Should I use it because it is not posible to use @Formula if the table you are trying to use is not the same as the entity where you want to use it?

Comment: yes, because with other entity you have some relationship with that. by using that relationship you can achieve your target.

Comment: Thanks Irfan. Can you try to do this case? Because I cant. A User has a Profile and a Vote. I need to fetch the userVotes from Profile into User. Let me add some more information in the question.